# How to shift subview of UITextView by size of one line when cursor goes to next line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

[image: screenshot of app]
I have a textView and I added an image to this textView. When i write text and go to next line I want to shift this image down by size of one line.. Similar like in twitter app when you create a tweet with picture. In this code I can shift picture by line, but my problem is it shifts to late (only on second symbol of next line).. I tried to use different values in CGSizeMake but line was shifted too early or too late.. Any recommendations?

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

    CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(self.textView.contentSize.width, self.textView.contentSize.height);
    UIFont *fontText = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];

    CGRect textRect = [textView.text boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:fontText}
                                         context:nil];

    size = textRect.size;

    CGFloat height = ceilf(size.height);
    CGFloat width  = ceilf(size.width);

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, height+50, 100.0f, 100);
    _imageView.frame=frame;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you add images just to help people visualize the issue?

Comment: Do adding pin constraints work?

Comment: No, constraints don't work.

Comment: the problem actually is the self.textView.contentSize.height changes  on second symbol of next line not on first symbol.. how force it to change on first symbol..

Answer (score 0):

You are hardcoding your font size. Maybe the text field has a different font. Use `textField.font` instead.

Also, you should simplify your code and eliminate the unused variables, such as `width`.

Finally, you should set a breakpoint where you calculate the size and keep checking if it is correct. Based on that it should be easy to debug.

Also, please note that `textField.text` does not yet contain the text that is going to be added. Before checking the size, you would have to first construct the new resulting string yourself.

```
NSString *newText = [textField.text 
    stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add your `Image` as `subview` to `superview` of your `textView`.
In `shouldChangeTextInRange:` fit frame of `textView` to `content` of `textView`.
Then just use **KVO** for catch moments, when frame of `textView` was changed. So, now you can keep top border of image on bottom border of textview, even animated!

I wont write code instead you, but it sound very easily and interesting, right?